# Classify the fastest and longest growing/decresing portions in a series of plotted values

Tags: matlab

I have a series of plotted values `(x, y)`. I'm searching for a way to classify each segments `{(Xi, Yi), (Xi+1, Yi+1)}` by fastest **and** longest growing/decresing slope.
[image: Plotted values]

In example image, segment (620, 635) has slope greater than segment (516, 550) but the second segment is longer than the first. So in this chartsegment (516, 550) will be the first, cause present very high slope and it's really long. 
Second place for segment (620, 635) which has really high slope but a length smaller than previous segment. How can I compute this in matlab?

Comment: 1) What is you criteria exactely? How do you want to combine speed and lenght? There are many ways to do so. 2) Do you want to take into account the case where several point are decreasing in a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given two vectors `x` and `y` defining your line segments, the length of each segment is:

```
sqrt(diff(x).^2 + diff(y).^2);
```

and the absolute value of the slope of each segment (since that seems to be what you are using) is

```
abs(diff(y)./diff(x));
```

Now combine these two together in some suitable way to give a metric, depending on the importance of each to your application. For example, assigning twice the weight to the slope:

```
metric = sqrt(diff(x).^2 + diff(y).^2) + 2*abs(diff(y)./diff(x));
```

Then sort on this metric:

```
[~, IX] = sort(metric, 'descend');
```

`IX(1)` will be the index into a vector of slope segments of the segment with the largest value of your chosen metric. Its endpoints are `[x(IX(1)), y(IX(1))]` and `[x(IX(1)+1), y(IX(1)+1)]`.
You can use an arbitrarily complex function of the slopes & lengths as your metric, if it is important for your application. If it is possible in your application for two `x`  values to be identical, you will need to handle the resulting `NaN`s carefully!

Comment: It was sound really intersting, but is quite difficult choose a proper parameter for metric. Leaving the same metric as you wrote, the segment (516, 550) is the sixth in this chart. But in my mind it should be the first. Even if I found a proper metric, I'm not really sure that right parameters for this graph will be suitable for every graphes. So probably need a different strategy. I've thinked to compute the area of triangles realized by segment (the hypothenuse) and parallel of x and y axes (cathetuses). What do you think? Could be area a most reliable metric?

Comment: Without knowing what you are trying to achieve, it is difficult to suggest an ideal metric, and the one I picked was just a random choice. But you can experiment: my suggested answer is just a way of combining multiple 'features' of the line segments and sorting on the combination. You aren't limited to two features: you could add diff(x).*diff(y) (which is twice the area you mentioned) as another term in the metric. Also you aren't restricted to a weighted sum of features: you can use powers, products, almost anything you like.

Comment: It's to difficult to explain what I really like, cause the main problem is really big and complex. Matter of fact is: the fastest and longest growing/decresing segment are significant point of my problem so the points inside that segments need further analysis. Anyway your answer gave me new ideas, so thank you. I'm experimented the area solution, hope that this will avoid me the research of proper metric.